# Show/hide widget with drop-down drawer animation with Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

With flutter, is there a way to show or hide widget with this type of animation :

[image]

Thanks in advance, :)

Comment: you can check AnimatedSize widget

Comment: you can use expansion panel . docs at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanel-class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use the [Expandable](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable)

```
ExpandableNotifier(  // <-- Provides ExpandableController to its children
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Expandable(           // <-- Driven by ExpandableController from ExpandableNotifier
        collapsed: ExpandableButton(  // <-- Expands when tapped on the cover photo
          child: buildCoverPhoto(),
        ),
        expanded: Column(  
          children: [
            buildAllPhotos(),
            ExpandableButton(       // <-- Collapses when tapped on
              child: Text("Back"),
            ),
          ]
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this type of animation using Animated Switcher. Create two different widgets. The first widget is the card you click on; the rest are the columns you show on. You can quickly achieve this by using the combination of Value Notifier and Animated Switcher widget